# how to fetch records from two tables using foreign key

Tags: ios, sqlite, join, foreign-keys

```
create table  studentsDetail (
    student_id integer primary key,
    rollno text,
    name text,
    stream text,
    school text
);

create table studentsInfo (
    studentinfo_id integer primary key,
    stdetail_info_id integer,
    fathername  text,
    mothername text,
    age text,
    address text,
    FOREIGN KEY(stdetail_info_id) REFERENCES studentsDetail(student_id)
);
```

I want to fetch record from both table using foreign key. How can I do it easily?

Comment: you need to have a field studentinfo_id in studentsInfo table or other way round to link these tables

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  studentsDetail.name, studentsDetail.school,
  studentsInfo.age, studentsInfo.address
FROM
  studentsDetail INNER JOIN studentsInfo
    ON studentsDetail.student_id = studentsInfo.stdetail_info_id
```

Comment: in this query where i have to pass the dynamic values to retrieve the data